# Is it possible to execute python script on Visual studio with Linux environment

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to execute python script  on Visual studio with Linux environment

For example

The following python code was written on the visual studio

```
import os
f = os.popen('date')
now = f.read()
print "Today is ", now
```

Usually after I write the code on the visual studio, then I send the python file to the Linux machine and I run the python  on Linux environment

And that because we cant run python code that fit for linux on win

Please advice if there are some alternative to run the python on Visual studio or other editors with Linux environment?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script

Comment: [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) might be what you are looking for. It is a .NET implementation for Linux. It may have some python plugins as well. I've used the Eclipse Python plugin as well with great success, and I believe Eclipse is available on Linux

Comment: something not clearly here , for example - if I have linux machine with IP - 123.3.4.2 ( with python ) , how the editor ( VS or Eclipse ) know to connect the linux ? and run the python scripts?